# What is generating redis cmd=info in CLIENT LIST?

Tags: redis

Is their a way to track down what was actually ran when cmd=info was generated in redis? I'm trying to track down a growing list of unclosed connections in redis.

`id=1937 addr=127.0.0.1:59324 fd=5 name= age=70915 idle=70915 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info`

Comment: The last command that the client executed is `INFO`

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc is hard in this case, but you can use [`CLIENT SETNAME`](https://redis.io/commands/client-setname) in your code for next time. The 'name' will be returned by `CLIENT LIST`.